# First character disappearing from command reading [Batch file]

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to read the output of a command (which outputs into multiple lines), and use an arbitrary number of those lines. Because I know neither the number of total lines, nor the number of lines that will be used, I need to analyse and possibly use each line in a loop, which is why I have `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Below is a snippet of the code that shows the process of taking the command and reading each line (not using it yet, just reading it to make sure this works (which it doesn't)):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('svn status') do (
echo %%i
set file=%%i
echo *!file!
)
```

The problem that I'm running into is that the `%%i` values that are being read in are not correct in the `for` line. The first character is missing from the first line of the input (which is important because I use the first line to decide whether or not to use that line).

The output I get from my code looks like this:

> ```
>        Dir0\TestDoc7.txt
> ?       StatusFile.txt
> ```

Whereas if I run this code:

```
copy /y NUL StatusFile.txt >NUL
>StatusFile.txt (
  svn status
)
```

(Which is just another way of me seeing what the real output of `svn status` is) I get a proper output into the text file:

> ```
> !       Dir0\TestDoc7.txt
> ?       StatusFile.txt
> ```

I'm probably making a fairly clear mistake as I'm rather new to batch scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is EnableDelayedExpansion which will **eat** the exclamation marks,
Your choice of `tokens=*` will also strip all leading spaces from the lines.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('svn status') do (
    if "%%A" equ "!" (
        Rem do whatever 
    ) else If "%%A" equ "?" (
        Rem do something else rest of the line is in %%B
    ) else (
        Rem no ! or ? first space sep. content is in %%A rest of the line is in %%B
    )
)
```

Comment: When delayed expansion is enabled, it does not eat the !. Just cmd interpreter parses every ! As a variable "opener/closer".